# iOS swift reachability should fail while login page exists

Tags: ios, swift, reachability

I am connecting my iPad to a Wi-Fi hotspot which requires users to login with a web page. If I do not login at that page, the internet connection is blocked. However, the reachability method below always returns `true` i.e. `httpResponse.statusCode == 200`. The Swift code is as below.

```
public class Reachability {

    class func isConnectedToNetwork()->Bool{

        var Status:Bool = false
        let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.google.com/")
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
        request.HTTPMethod = "HEAD"
        request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData
        request.timeoutInterval = 10.0

        var response: NSURLResponse?

        var data = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: &response, error: nil) as NSData?

        if let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {

            if httpResponse.statusCode == 200 {
                Status = true
            }
        }

        return Status
    }
}
```

What I want is:

- Wi-Fi login web page exists => return false status
- Wi-Fi login web page disappears => return true status

I have tried some reachability codes, the results are the same. Is it possible to get a false connection status while the actual internet connection is still blocked by the Wi-Fi login control?

Answer (score 0):

What you want and what you get are two entirely different things. Life is tough. Whenever you use http, expect to get a reply that has nothing to do whatsoever with that you were asking for. Whenever you use https, expect a reply with a certificate that doesn't match the site you were asking for.

Yes, you will be told that there is a WiFi connection to the Internet when what you got was a login page. If you are lucky enough to have a BT Homehub router, for example, when your Internet connection goes down, the router will return a website trying to tell you that the internet connection is down, with a valid 200 status.

Conclusion: Be prepared to handle *anything* you get from a server without crashing and without doing stupid things.

Answer (score 0):

```
    if let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {

        if httpResponse.statusCode == 200 {
            Status = true
        } else{
          Status = false
        }

    }
```